# How to know when your Chrome application Window is fully open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am creating a Chrome application, "not a extension."
People can receive and send messages. If i receive a message, i got a notification and a mp3 sound. If the app Window is open, I know how to focus the window to make it appear to the front. but if the window is closed. I do get the notification, the sound ect (from background.js) and i create a window to open, when i receive this notification, but i can't interact with the background.js script anymore. is like if the chrome.runtime.sendMessage fire to soon before my app window is fully open.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  action: "Messageincoming"
});
```

When a message is incoming, in my app, a popup appear telling the user that a message is incoming (called from background.js) and the user can accept it by clicking a button. but when the app window is closed i should open a new window and i open it programatically with `chrome.app.window.create('myapp.html', {`

Like i said the chrome.runtime.sendMessage seem to fire to soon before the window is fully open. I can't trigger this popup to make the user accept, and i am not sure that if i do that the button will work.

Is there a way to wait until the window is fully open? or use any other method. 
i read all the chrome app documentation and i find nothing. I have a js scripts in the myapp.html page who control the click and everything in the UI. controler.js

Comment: i find out, i just wait for jQuery ready, i send a message to my background.js and it send back a message to my js file inside my html page.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways to do this, so it really depends on what you're looking for. The likely simplest answer is through a callback function, which you can pass in to chrome.app.window.create as shown [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create). This will allow you to pass in a function to be executed during page load.

Another way is to receive a message as you've described. You can do that as well, but you need to set a message handler in the new page you've created, and it needs to be set immediately on page load or else you will miss the message as you've described. Here's more on message passing with some examples at the bottom.  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

A more elaborate method of doing this could be to hook into the OnFullscreened or other handlers for the new window. In that handler, send a request to your background script requesting whatever message data you need. In your background script, have a message handler that returns whatever stored message(s) you want.